# Get simple product Id from configurable in Magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I have **configurable product** with 3 colors(red,Blue,green) in drop down.If I have selected **red** color product,How to get red color product Id in product page

If anyone knows please help me

Comment: you want that id in js or in php class?

Comment: php class......

Comment: You can append product id in swatch create function in `swatch-renderer.js` so you can have that id while you select that option.

Comment: please show your code where you want to get product id.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: Where you want to get selected product id while add to cart?

Comment: In block file..

Answer (score 4):

**We can use this function to get the child product of configurable product.

We need to pass the configurable product id, attribute code and value.**

```
public function getChildProductOfConfigByAttrValue($configProdId, $attr_code, $attr_value){
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($configProdId);
$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

$productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
$productTypeInstance->setStoreFilter($storeId, $product);
$usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);     

foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) {

            $customValue = $child->getAttributeText($attr_code);
            if($customValue == $attr_value){
                return $child->getId();
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: $value means..how to get value?

Comment: $value will be 'red' for your case.

Comment: $attr will be 'color'.

Comment: OK.I will try this...

Comment: $attr will be 'color'.
But if you want to get these value dynamic from the cart then there will be different solution.

Comment: Yes.I want  to get these value dynamically

Comment: // You can get it from the cart object. It will give you the simple product id of congifurable product. You just need to pass the configurable product id.
Like->
$parent_product_id = 10;
foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
if($productId == $parent_product_id){
 if ($option = $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
         $option->getProduct()->getId();
    }
}
   
}

Comment: But i want details in product page/Before adding product in cart